# Diagnosing random-like crashes of Windows 8.1 Update 2 desktop

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze, crash, bsod

I'm diagnosing my mother's computer (HP Desktop) and the symptom is random freezes and blue screens.  Generally speaking, I'm pretty good at fixing machines (Sr. Software Engineer, I am) but this one has me stumped... at her house, it freezes and BSoD's after a few minutes of use, constantly.  At MY house, sometimes it will show the symptoms, but not often... when I brought it home today, it BSoD'd within minutes of booting, but after that, has been running and has been actively used for hours with several programs.  When it crashes, there are no significant event log errors.  I immediately thought "power issue" at her house, but even on a battery backup it shows these symptoms.  The BSoD errors are highly variable... The latest being "BAD_POOL_HEADER" (I'll update this question with other errors as I encounter them)... I've reinstalled Windows from scratch and replaced the HD with an SSD.  I've brought home every piece of hardware she's plugged into to attempt to simulate the issue, but again it runs fine (mostly) at my house.  I'm going to start looking into "heat-related" and "memory" issues next, but I thought I'd throw this out and see if anyone has any out-of-the-box suggestions.

Comment: With zero information about the state of the machine at the time of the BSOD we cannot help you.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's vague.... I'm grasping here. :)

Comment: BlueScreeViewer is an excellent way to provide us the information we need.

Comment: Seems to happen most often in NTOSKRNL.EXE at address 150ca0... and most often seem to be memory errors... wonder if I have a bad DIMM... will concentrate on that... thanks for the pointer...

Comment: That really isn't what I was looking for.  There are existing questions that describe in detail how to debug something like this, outside of that, we can provide specific help if we have the information or find what might be the duplicate.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx activate **driver verifier** (special pool) for 3rd party drivers wait for the next crash and share the newest dmp file from **C:\Windows\Minidump**